# Installing phpunit to a Laravel 4 site

Tags: tdd, phpunit, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When reading through a Laravel book, why does the author recommend installing `phpunit` as a `require-dev` in the `composer.json` file?

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
...
```

I did `composer update` and it installed `phpunit` anyway, so why not put it under `require`?

Answer (score 2):

That's because "require" contains the packages required for the application while "require-dev" contains the packages required for developing the application.

http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require
http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev

The dev requirements will only be installed if you run `install --dev`, so it gives you the option to install packages required to prepare a dev environment or not.

PHP Unit's docs show it being included in composer.json both ways. It just depends if you want it as a development-time dependency only.

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html